# getting mysql error 1054

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1054

I am getting this error: #1054 - Unknown column 't.mobile' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT t.*,v.name,v.contact_person_email,l.firstname as memname 
FROM transactions t , vendor v
LEFT JOIN loyalty_members l ON (t.mobile=l.mobile) 
WHERE t.vendor_id ='N1WU95' 
AND v.alert_mail = '2'
AND t.add_date  <= '2011-07-22 09:00:00'
AND t.add_date >= '2011-07-21 09:00:00'
AND t.vendor_id = v.id
AND t.type = '1' 
AND t.deleted != '1'
AND t.reference_id = '0'
GROUP BY t.mobile 
HAVING COUNT(t.mobile) > 1;
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the column `mobile` exist in the table `transactions`?

Comment: And so we see another example why SELECT * is bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
   SELECT t.*, v.name, v.contact_person_email, l.firstname memname 
     FROM vendor v, transactions t
LEFT JOIN loyalty_members l ON t.mobile = l.mobile 
    WHERE t.vendor_id ='N1WU95' 
      AND v.alert_mail = '2'
      AND t.add_date  <= '2011-07-22 09:00:00' 
      AND t.add_date >= '2011-07-21 09:00:00' 
      AND t.vendor_id = v.id 
      AND t.type = '1' 
      AND t.deleted != '1' 
      AND t.reference_id = '0' 
 GROUP BY t.mobile 
   HAVING COUNT(t.mobile) > 1;
```

You were doing a `LEFT JOIN` with the wrong table sequence. The engine was trying to join `vendor` table with `loyalty_members` table.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the order of the table sequence could have that affect. Nicely spotted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, the "mobile" column from the table `transactions` does not exist.

Comment: @ScottMcGready: Nope, this is not it. I suspected it to be the one, but on a second glance the OP is doing a `LEFT JOIN` on `vendors` table with `loyalty_members`, which obviously is not the right order. @ceejayoz: Seems like this wasn't clear enough. :)